# Debugging Dynamic Links error: "iOS store ID does not exist in the given iOS bundle ID."

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, bundle-identifier

**Debugging Dynamic Links error: "iOS store ID does not exist in the given iOS bundle ID."**

I create a Dynamic Link for my project, completed all setups
Android works perfectly, but iOS is unable to redirect to App Store when the app is not installed, when I debug the Dynamic Link in the console, get the error "iOS store ID does not exist in the given iOS bundle ID."

**Error msg screenshot**
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMMpF.png)

I have checked and made sure that the Bundle ID, APP ID, and Team ID are set correctly. However, the same error still occurs and the iOS app does not redirects to the app store if it is not installed.

Have you ever encountered a similar error when using Firebase deeplinks? need your help!

**My iOS App setup in Firebase:**
[Firebase APP Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SWBJ.png)
[Dynamic Link Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t003o.png)

**Long Dynamic Link**
https://fhmw.page.link/?link=https://www.fullertonhealth.com/&apn=com.mwpcp.android&isi=1614099585&ibi=com.fhn3.mwpcp

**Debug Dynamic Link**
https://fhmw.page.link/debug?d=1

**My iOS App setup in AppStore Connect:**
[AppStore Connect Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTKx1.png)

**Team ID:**
[Team ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOpNW.png)

**AppStore Page:**
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fhmw/id1614099585

Very confused, Need your valuable advice！

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Found this useful [comment](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8758) on this post that helped solve my issue.

Had duplicate IDs on my project's Credentials page in the Google Cloud Console. Just deleted them and kept the one that was correct.

Comment: You should avoid relying on links, because links eventually go away. It is ok to use links, just include some descriptive information to support the answer, without me having to click on the link

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

I was running into the same exact problem. Thanks to Daniel's answer, I looked into an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/8758) on the firebase-iOS-sdk's repository.

Apparently, this was caused because there were multiple OAuth 2.0 Client IDs associated with my app's bundle ID. Every time you change/add a bundle ID in the firebase console, a new OAuth 2.0 Client ID will be auto-generated (You can view these for your project [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)). I had changed my bundle ID and changed it back multiple times so there were duplicates and Client IDs associated with the wrong bundle ID.

**SOLUTION**

To solve this, all I had to do was remove all of the duplicate (or incorrect) 'iOS Client' IDs from the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), and I was able to get the dynamic link to start working.

In the end, make sure there is only one OAuth 2.0 Client ID associated with your app's bundle ID. Another thing that helped was checking Firebase's debug link feature. You can get there by going to Firebase console -> Dynamic Links -> Menu option on the right of a created link (three dots) -> Link preview (debug).

Hope this helped, let me know if you are still having problems!